# Как перемножить числа в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Пользователь вводит любые числа в строку, которые добавляются в список.

Сумму можно найти так: `sum(spisok)`.

А как найти произведение? Можно, вроде, циклом через `for`.

А если, например, нужно в одну строку, то как реализовать?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Раньше можно было использвать reduce(). Сейчас тоже можно, но эту функцию вынесли в отдельный модуль, так что строго говоря, считая импорт, получается две строчки:

```
import functools
print (functools.reduce(lambda a, b : a * b, lst))
```

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё и третью строчку, с импортом оператора умножения =) Upd: А, это есть ниже)

Comment: а почему сделали общим?

Comment: @Danis Я сам сделал, потому что код не мой и есть на многих страницах в интернете как иллюстрация к reduce()

Answer (score 12):

Все ответы здесь отстали от современности. Как насчет [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8) и выше?
[math.prod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod)

```py
import math
math.prod([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Это пожалуй самое простое и стандартное решение ИМХО.

Answer (score 9):

```py
from functools import reduce  # Функция для свёрки последовательности
from operator import mul  # Функция, перемножающая 2 числа

spisok = [16, 15, 9, 14, 13]  # Исходный список

result = reduce(mul, spisok)
#                    /\ Список для свёртки
#               /\ Используем умножение
#        /\ Сворачиваем контейнер
```

Answer (score 8):

Можно реализовать функцию `mul`

```
def mul(list_):
    n = 1
    for el in list_:
        n *= el
    return n
```

либо так, с помощью `lambda` и рекурсии

```
mul = lambda arr:arr[0] * mul(arr[1:]) if arr else 1
```

Comment: тут пять строк, не считая той, где это будет вызываться. Про for автор даже в вопросе сам написал.

Answer (score 8):

С импортом можно и так:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.prod(np.array(mylist))
```

Comment: Тяжеленный `numpy` для таких простейших задач...

Comment: @МихаилМуругов вопрос-то был "а можно ли сделать в одну строку?" - вот и приводим разные примеры

Answer (score 4):

```
let num = Number(prompt())
let lis = []
let mult = []

while (num) {
   num = Number(prompt())
   lis.append(num)
}
var m = 1
for (let n = 0; n < lis.length; n++) {
  m = m*lis[n]
  mult.append(m)
}
```

Comment: А где тут python?

Comment: а как это все записать в одну строчку?

Comment: @Эникейщик это даже не python))

Comment: )) правда, не обратил внимание, но это в целом не сложно должно быть переделать, если видишь на одном языке

Comment: @Alexander_Sky Ничего, я тут тоже поначалу путался где какой язык ))  А надо на тэги смотреть

Comment: Да, есть такое. Я знаю, что это можно переписать одной строчкой, ведь редюс есть и в JS, просто не подумал \ не часто пользовался

Answer (score 1):

Я приведу не очень практичное, но красивое решение в одну строку. Оно не использует `eval`, побочные эффекты при работе со списком или именованные функции.

Если именованные функции разрешены, то решение может выглядеть так:

```
def p(a):
    if a:
        return a[0] * p(a[1:])
    return 1

print(p([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Нам оно не подходит, так именованная функция требует минимум две строки для определения и вызова. Лямбду можно определить и вызвать в одной строке, но есть трудность в создании рекурсивной лямбды. Синтаксис Python разрешает такой трюк:

```
p = (lambda a: a[0] * p(a[1:]) if a else 1); print(p([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Это именно трюк с глобальной переменной и двумя операторами в одной строке. А можно обойтись без глобальной переменной вообще. На первый взгляд этого не может быть так как имя нужно чтобы сделать рекурсивный вызов. Но функцию можно передать как аргумент в саму себя:

```
p = lambda f, a: a[0] * f(f, a[1:]) if a else 1
print(p(p, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Кажется мы ничего не выиграли: всё равно два оператора и глобальная переменная `p`. Однако сделан очень важный шаг - тело лямбды не использует глобальные переменные. Глобальная переменная используется в операторе `print`. Избавимся от неё:

```
p = lambda f, a: a[0] * f(f, a[1:]) if a else 1
y = lambda f, a: f(f, a)
print(y(p, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Стало только хуже: три строки и две глобальные переменные. Зато каждая глобальная переменная задействована только один раз. Делаем подстановку:

```
print((lambda f, a: f(f, a))(lambda f, a: a[0] * f(f, a[1:]) if a else 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Читается тяжело, но задача решена в одну строку без глобальных имён и волшебных вызовов `eval`.

P.S. Читайте [Fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) чтобы узнать откуда пошло это решение.

P.P.S. Красивое утверждение: программу любой сложности можно записать в функциональном стиле не определив ни одной глобальной переменной, включая имена функций.

P.P.P.S. Не пытайтесь повторить это дома.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(eval(str(d)[1:-1].replace(',', '*')))
```

Comment: Вы хотели сказать `eval('*'.join(map(str, d)))`?

Comment: Лучше не использовать eval, когда нужно всего лишь перемножить числа.

Comment: @insolor Лучше не использовать `eval` точка ;)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, именно так!

Answer (score 0):

Если очень захотеть, то можно и в одну строчку записать, но так конечно делать не стоит
, например перемножить '2 3 4 5' = 120

```
print(list(map(lambda s, t=[1]: [t.append(i*t[-1]) for i in map(int, s.split())][0] or t[-1], ['2 3 4 5']))[0])  # 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
output = 1
for i in arr:
    output *= i
print(output) #120
```

Comment: Автор вопроса интересовался однострочным решением, про цикл `for` он был в курсе.